# 'Chained' WPF binding

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I'm creating a UserControl in WPF, which I'm calling YesNoButton.

It has a single DependencyProperty, IsChecked, and contains two ToggleButtons, with labels "Yes" and "No". I've bound the IsChecked property of the the *Yes* ToggleButton to this IsChecked property of the parent YesNoButton. I've bound the IsChecked property of the *No* ToggleButton to the IsChecked property of the the *Yes* ToggleButton, through an 'inverse boolean' IValueConverter. Here's my YesNoButton markup, minus some of the look and feel frill:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ToggleButton x:Name="YesButton" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Controls:YesNoButton}}, Path=IsChecked}">Yes</ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=YesButton, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToInverseConverter}}">No</ToggleButton>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

In my app, I include the YesNoButton as follows:

```
<local:YesNoButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=BoolPropertyOfDataContext}" />
```

When the window first loads, if I toggle the BoolPropertyOfDataContext by other means, the YesNoButton reacts perfectly.

But as soon as I click the Yes or No ToggleButton, although the YesNoButton visual state updates correctly, the binding to the BoolPropertyOfDataContext stops working altogether - it seems to be cancelled. I thought these 'binding chains' were supposed to work fine, but I'm obviously missing something here!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by styling a CheckBox instead:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=BoolPropertyOfDataContext}" Style="{StaticResource YesNoButton}" />

<Style x:Key="YesNoButton" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="YesButton" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type CheckBox}}, Path=IsChecked}">Yes</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=YesButton, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToInverseConverter}}">No</ToggleButton>
                </StackPanel>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. Name your UserControl so that you can refer to it
2. Bind both ToggleButton IsChecked states to the IsChecked property for the UserControl

For example:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=YesNoButton, Path=IsChecked}">Yes</ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=YesNoButton, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToInverseConverter}}">No</ToggleButton>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried (1) already - no difference. I tried removing the No ToggleButton altogether and it still didn't work, so I assume (2) would not help. I know in the past when I have manually set the IsChecked property of a control to some value, that it's bindings were destroyed. I assume something similar is happening here, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: How is BoolPropertyOfDataContext implemented? Is it a dependency property? Also, do you notice any messages in the Output Window if you run under the debugger?

Comment: BoolPropertyOfDataContext is a Boolean field of an Entity Framework Entity object (and so has property change notification). No messages in output window unfortunately!

Comment: Got it working a completely different way (see my edited post), but I still don't know why my first attempt didn't work!